# Debug clang C++ code with vscode under WSL

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang, lldb

I have a C/C++ test example under WSL-Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Win10:

```
>:~/projects/test$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

>:~/projects/test$ pwd
/home/user1/projects/test

>:~/projects/test$ ls
main  main.cpp
```

Code *main.cpp*:

```
#include <iostream>
  
int main() 
{

    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
  
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it under vscode with this *task.json*

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't debug it - this is my *launch.json*

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb-mi"
        }
    ]
}
```

Under Windows10, WSL-Ubuntu has that *clang* and *lldb-mi* installed

```
>:~/projects/test$ whereis lldb-mi
lldb-mi: /usr/bin/lldb-mi /usr/share/man/man1/lldb-mi.1.gz

>:~/projects/test$ ls
main  main.cpp

>:~/projects/test$ whereis clang
clang: /usr/bin/clang /usr/lib/clang /usr/include/clang /usr/share/man/man1/clang.1.gz

>:~/projects/test$ whereis clang++
clang++: /usr/bin/clang++
```

Versions for *clang*, *lldb*

```
>:~/projects/test$ lldb --version
lldb version 10.0.0

>:~/projects/test$ clang --version
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin

>:~/projects/test$
```

[image]

My installed and used vscode plugins:

[image]

How to properly configure vscode, *task.json*, *launch.json*, WSL-Ubuntu to have C/C++ code compiling and debugging with *clang* and its *lldb-mi*?

Comment: It might be better if the release version of ubuntu is mentioned, e.g. ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: What C/C++ plugin do you use for VSCode? cpptools, clangd, codelldb, or what others? It be might be better to mention them.

Comment: WSL:Ubuntu installed plugins: CodeLLDB, C++ Intellisense, C/C++

Comment: Well in my experience Clangd + CodeLLDB should works fine, and I don't use C++ Intellisense. (I gennerate `compile_commands.json` file for function/variable definition jumping). And if cpptools is installedd, it will conflict with Clangd+CodeLLDB.

Answer (score 1):

My work around is change `MIMode`:

```json
//"MIMode": "lldb",
"MIMode": "gdb",  // should have gdb installed
```

And comment out `miDebuggerPath`:

```json
//"miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb-mi"
```

<del>Don't know if there is better solution.</del>
For lldb and lldb-mi on ubuntu, people have to compile lldb-mi manually:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5415#issuecomment-662603085

Comment: it works with gdb as you suggested :) - so it means no lldb possible?